# Problem Running Honeyd

Tags: networking

Problem Running Honeyd , appears caption "bad interface configuration eth0 is not ip" how do I resolve this problem ?

Thank you for that answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Type `man -k honeyd` and read the resulting `man` pages. From just the error message, all I can suggest is that, somewhere in your `honeyd` configuration you have `eth0` set to something OTHER than an "ip address", e.g.`192.168.100.77` (this could be what it expects, although the Right value for your system will differ).

**R**ead **T**he **F**ine **M**anual.

Comment: So, what should I do? whether it should be " 192.168.100.77 "